# Python, Django 2.1 - suggestion and guidance please

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, saas

A very good evening to Everyone. I am a frontend 3D developer well versed with Python and JavaScript. Recently I created a frontend application for interior designing based on webgl. I now want to invest my time in making it a SAAS application using Django. Well my experience with Django is minimal with only experience doing a to-do list based on a tutorial, lol. The frontend of the app is only part (~30%) of the final goal. The product is aimed at manufactures and freelancers in interior designing and should use subscription model. Based on the subscription plans the abilities vary. The main vision is to help manufactures in handling projects with designers both in-house and by employing freelancers.

Technically this translates to user types who are 1) individuals, 2) groups, and 3) subgroups. Also there are assets(meshes, textures) that are available as private and public access. One possibility in the roadmap is including the ability of groups to be able to White label the app (custom domain, Logo etc). Finally, the last part of the vision is social media and I am planning to use LinkedIn for this purpose.

Coming to my experience with Django is quite minimal but I was able to understand the fundamentals in having apps, models etc. My question can be summarised to a list of requirements,

1- groups, subgroups, individuals
2- subscription plans and setting limits
3- subdomain and white labeling.

Now, is it better off to write from scratch? Or use some existing Django based apps and integrate to the whole pipeline? Should I use a CMS or CRM? Can you all please guide me with your wisdom.

Also my sincere apologies on my post exhibiting anything ignorant, if any. For it wouldn't have been intentional. Many thanks in advance.

Regards,

## 0K